# Anonymous Function not working with keydown events

Tags: javascript

Wondering what I'm doing wrong here - the function is supposed to look at all the cells in a table, add their default background color, font color and border color and then add an Event Listener to each that executes the anonymouse function to change a cells formatting depending on what key is held down onmousedown. It does the initial styling of all the cells correctly but that's it.

```
function setupPuzzle() {
  allCells = document.querySelectorAll("table#hitoriGrid td");
  for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
    allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
    allCells[i].addEventListener("onmousedown", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
      } else if (e.altKey) {
        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
      } else {
        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(101,101,101)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "50%";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `mousedown` instead of `onmousedown`
2. because your anonymous function invoked after the loop (When the user clicked it) then `i` value will be the last value of `i`.
   so you need to use `this` instead of `allCells[i]`.

```js
function setupPuzzle() {
allCells = document.querySelectorAll("table#hitoriGrid td");
for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
    
    allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";

    
    allCells[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();         
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        this.style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        this.style.borderRadius = "0px";
    }
    else if (e.altKey) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        this.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        this.style.borderRadius = "0px";
    }
    else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(101,101,101)";
        this.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        this.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    }
    }); 
}
}

setupPuzzle();
```

```html
<table id="hitoriGrid" border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Huge help! That makes so much more sense, ty!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you are listening for an onmousedown event so e.altKey and e.shiftKey is always false because the event passed to your callback function is an onmousedown event. I am not sure if you can actually read if a key is already pressed but one of solutions that come to my mind is to listen on events for keydown and store something like:

```
var keyPressed = [];
window.onkeyup = function(e) {keys[e.keyCode]=false;}
window.onkeydown = function(e) {keys[e.keyCode]=true;}
```

Then on mouse down event you can check in an array if key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** use `mousedown` instead of `onmousedown` for the event name as pointed out by the other answers. This edit has been made in the below code:

---

The issue is that `i` does not point to the value that you expect it to. The scope of `i` is not confined to the block that it is contained in, so all of your `onmousedown` callbacks are going to reference an `i` that is equal to `allCells.length + 1`

`i` is incremented by 1 on each iteration of the for-loop, and this `i` value is shared by all of your `onmousedown` handlers, so by the time your for-loop finishes running, your handlers will all refer to `i`, which will be `allCells.length + 1` as that is the last value `i` takes before the for-loop exits.

If you are using ES6, you can use `let` instead of `var` in your for-loop to fix the issue:

```
function setupPuzzle() {

  allCells = document.querySelectorAll("table#hitoriGrid td");

  for (let i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) { // uset let instead of var

    allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
    allCells[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
      } else if (e.altKey) {
        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
      } else {
        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(101,101,101)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "50%";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you are not using ES6, you can use a **closure** to make sure that `i` is scoped at the block-level (and therefore all of your event handlers will have their own reference of `i`):

```
function setupPuzzle() {

  allCells = document.querySelectorAll("table#hitoriGrid td");

  for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) { 

    (function(i) { // closure

        allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
        allCells[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (e.shiftKey) {
            allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
            allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
          } else if (e.altKey) {
            allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
            allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
          } else {
            allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(101,101,101)";
            allCells[i].style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
            allCells[i].style.borderRadius = "50%";
          }
        });

    })(i); // captures surrounding value of i

  }
}
```